# Removing entity when entity splitting used

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm building Reporting system, but having problem with removing data from db.

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? DateRange { get; set; }
    public int Layout { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<ReportCharts> ReportCharts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportElements> ReportElements { get; set; }
}

public class ReportElements
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
}

public class ReportCharts
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ChartId { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext:

```
    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }

    // Report entity mapping
    protected virtual void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.ReportId).HasColumnName("ReportId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateRange).HasColumnName("DateRange");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Layout).HasColumnName("Layout");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateFrom).HasColumnName("DateFrom");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateTo).HasColumnName("DateTo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.OwnerId).HasColumnName("OwnerId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Active).HasColumnName("Active");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportElements).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.ReportId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportCharts).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.ReportId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportElements>().Property(c => c.ElementName).HasColumnName("ElementName");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportElements>().HasKey(c => new { c.ReportId, c.ElementName, c.Active });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCharts>().Property(p => p.ChartId).HasColumnName("ChartId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCharts>().HasKey(c => new { c.ReportId, c.ChartId, c.Active });
    }
```

In EF repository:

```
    public void RemoveReport(Report rep)
    {
        context.Reports.Remove(rep);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I perform delete it deletes only from Report table, and not from all three. When I do save report it saves in all three tables. So don't really understand what is wrong.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportElements)
                            .WithRequired()
                            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ReportId)
                            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportCharts)
                            .WithRequired()
                            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ReportId)
                            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: It still doesn't delete them

Comment: is it something that I need to set up on SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything in SQL Server to make it work.

Comment: I found it, to make WillCascadeInDelete() work, I have to set up tables relationship in SQL Server and set Delete Rule to Cascade. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into cascading delete options in Entity Framework an apply them as you need them.